# How can I replace link_with with abstract_target?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I updated the gem pod and I am now getting an error while compiline Signal-iOS. Here is the error I am getting:

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] The specification of `link_with` in
>   the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..

Here is the content of the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
link_with ["Signal", "SignalTests"]
```

I have absolutely no familiarity with CocosPod so this is gibberish to me. I spent time reading online docs, but there is a bit of conflicting information due to the recent changes and deprecation of commands. What is the recommended way to change the file so the project can build again?

Comment: I have also get issue from `link_with 'ChatSecure', 'ChatSecureTests'` . any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it would be like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Signal' do
  pod 'SignalServiceKit',           :git => 'https://github.com/WhisperSystems/SignalServiceKit.git'
  pod 'OpenSSL',                    '~> 1.0.208'
  pod 'PastelogKit',                '~> 1.3'
  pod 'FFCircularProgressView',     '~> 0.5'
  pod 'SCWaveformView',             '~> 1.0'
  pod 'DJWActionSheet'

  pod 'JSQMessagesViewController',  :git => 'https://github.com/WhisperSystems/JSQMessagesViewController', :commit => 'e5582fef8a6b3e35f8070361ef37237222da712b'

  target 'SignalTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

I've recommended it on this PR: https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-iOS/pull/1180

Comment: How did you get that version of openssl to work. I am getting `[!] Unable to find a specification for `OpenSSL (~> 1.0.208)``

Comment: Follow up: I solved this by upgrading to `ruby 2.3.1p112` and updating all pods after doing `sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`. Things are finally working now.